# How to read a header from a specific line with CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to read a CSV file where header is at row 3:

```
some crap line
some empty line
COL1,COL2,COl3,...
val1,val2,val3
val1,val2,val3
```

How do I tell [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) the header is not at the first row?

I tried to skip 2 lines with `Read()` but the succeeding call to `ReadHeader()` throws an exception that the header has already been read.

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream), csvConfiguration)) {
   csv.Read();
   csv.Read();
   csv.ReadHeader();
   .....
```

If I set `csvConfiguration.HasHeaderRecord` to `false` `ReadHeader()` fails again.

Comment: Most CSV readers have an option skip the first lines in order to avoid titles etc. If CsvReader doesn't have that option, just read a couple of lines, as Evk shows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
      reader.ReadLine();
      reader.ReadLine();
      using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader)) {                    
          csv.ReadHeader();                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**As of CsvHelper 27.0 the problem is no longer reproducible.** A header can now be read in from any line. This may have been implemented as far back as [Release 3.0.0 from 2017](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/3.0.0) which included, according to the [change log](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/):

> **3.0.0**
>
> Read more than 1 header row.

Thus the following code now just works, and has worked for a while:

```
var csvText = "some crap line\nsome empty line\nCOL1,COL2,COl3\nval1,val2,val3\nval1,val2,val3\n\n";
using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvText));

var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    // Your settings here.
};
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream), csvConfiguration))
{
    csv.Read(); // Read in the first row "some crap line"
    csv.Read(); // Read in the second row "some empty line"
    csv.Read(); // Read in the third row which is the actual header.
    csv.ReadHeader(); // Process the currently read row as the header.

    Assert.AreEqual(3, csv.HeaderRecord.Length);
    Assert.AreEqual(@"COL1,COL2,COl3", String.Join(",", csv.HeaderRecord));
```

Successful demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7zdEX).

**Warning**: be aware that CsvHelper **skips blank lines by default** so if some of the preliminary lines to be skipped might or might not be blank, then `csv.Read()` might silently read past them -- and then consume your header also, resulting the the wrong row being used as a header row!

Failing demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DV5dU4).

To avoid this possibility and deterministically skip a certain number of lines at the beginning of the file, you must set [`CsvConfiguration.IgnoreBlankLines = false`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L82).  However, this property cannot be modified once the `CsvReader` is created, so if you need to skip blank data lines this can be accomplished by using a [`ShouldSkipRecord`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L147) callback:

```
bool ignoreBlankLines = false;
var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    IgnoreBlankLines = false,
    ShouldSkipRecord = (args) => !ignoreBlankLines ? false : args.Record.Length == 0 || args.Record.Length == 1 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Record[0]),
    // Your settings here.
};
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream), csvConfiguration))
{
    csv.Read(); // Read in the first row "some crap line"
    csv.Read(); // Read in the second empty row, which is empty.
    csv.Read(); // Read in the third row which is the actual header.
    csv.ReadHeader(); // Process the currently read row as the header.
    ignoreBlankLines = true; // Now that the header has been read, ignore blank data lines.
```

Successful demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LMoI60).

Comment: For me, `reader.Read()` didn't work because it checks the column count even for lines that should be skipped. `reader.Parser.Read()` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't better than Evk's answer, but I was interested.

The CsvConfiguration class appears to have a Func callback named ShouldSkipRecord that can be wired to to implement custom logic.

https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/tree/master/src/CsvHelper

CsvConfiguration.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the callback that will be called to
/// determine whether to skip the given record or not.
/// This overrides the <see cref="SkipEmptyRecords"/> setting.
/// </summary>
public virtual Func<string[], bool> ShouldSkipRecord { get; set; }
```

CsvReader.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Advances the reader to the next record.
/// If HasHeaderRecord is true (true by default), the first record of
/// the CSV file will be automatically read in as the header record
/// and the second record will be returned.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if there are more records, otherwise false.</returns>
public virtual bool Read()
{
    if (doneReading)
    {
        throw new CsvReaderException(DoneReadingExceptionMessage);
    }

    if (configuration.HasHeaderRecord && headerRecord == null)
    {
        ReadHeader();
    }

    do
    {
        currentRecord = parser.Read();
    }
    while (ShouldSkipRecord());

    currentIndex = -1;
    hasBeenRead = true;

    if (currentRecord == null)
    {
        doneReading = true;
    }

    return currentRecord != null;
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks if the current record should be skipped or not.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if the current record should be skipped, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
protected virtual bool ShouldSkipRecord()
{
    if (currentRecord == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return configuration.ShouldSkipRecord != null
        ? configuration.ShouldSkipRecord(currentRecord)
        : configuration.SkipEmptyRecords && IsRecordEmpty(false);
}
```

Unfortunately, it appears that you'd have to set HasHeaderRecord to false, then set it back to true, prior to calling ReadHeaders or calling Read on the third line, because the ShouldSkipRecord logic in Read() is after the ReadHeader() logic.