# Reading a CSV file from a specific row

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a an attendance sheet in weird CSV format from Microsoft teams which I need to store in the database. I upload the csv file (from above) and want to parse the data.
[image: Attendance Sheet]

I am just interested in getting email and join time.

This is what I have tried so far -

```
                    var path = Path.Combine(filePath, e.File.GetName());
                    var csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default).ToList();
                    List<Foo> lst = new List<Foo>();
                    foreach (var row in csvRows.Skip(7))
                    {
                      Foo foo = new Foo();
                      var columns = row.Split(';');
                       foo.JoinTime= columns[0];
                       foo.Email = columns[1];
                       lst.Add(foo);
                    }
```

I know I am close but wanted to explore a better approach and get the data in the right format.

Comment: CSV helper is a good library for reading csv. Related : [How to read a header from a specific line with CsvHelper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641220/how-to-read-a-header-from-a-specific-line-with-csvhelper).

Comment: I will also advice for never using picture on SO. If someone whanted to craft a solution he will have to type everything him self.

Comment: btw [`ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0) return an `string[]`. There is no need for a `ToList`. And if your intention are to skip 7 of them you can use [`ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0) Method that will return an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: So, whats not working in you current approach? Besides the obvious that the time is in `columns[1]` and email is in `columns[4]` and you probably need some kind of parsing for the time ...

Comment: You may also want to define better. Because you can one line `var result = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.Default).Skip(7).Select(x=> x.Split(';')).Select(x=> new Foo{JoinTime= columns[0],Email = columns[1]}).ToList();` But it will hardly be better or worst.

Comment: I am getting the data back but the format is all messed up because of comma within the date and name

Comment: CSVHelper is just recognizing the first header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/), you can parse your csv as shown below.

**PS.** This approach only works if there are fixed number of lines to be ignored in the CSV file

```
foreach (var rec in new ChoCSVReader("**** YOUR CSV FILE PATH ***")
    .HeaderLineAt(7)
    .WithDelimiter(";")
    .ConfigureHeader(h => h.HasHeaderRecord = true)
    )
{
    Console.WriteLine(rec["Full Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine(rec["Join Time"]);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on sample CSV provided below, here is the working sample.

Sample CSV you provided assumes tab separator.

```
            string csv = @"Meeting Summary
Total Number of Participants    4 
Meeting Title   Test 
Meeting Start Time  3/11/2021, 12:57:48 PM 
Meeting End Time    3/11/2021, 1:28:13 PM 

Full Name   Join Time   Leave Time  Duration    Email   Role 
Smith, John.    3/11/2021, 12:57:48 PM  3/11/2021, 1:28:08 PM   30m 20s TEST39@test.com Presenter 
Marshall, Micah D.  3/11/2021, 12:59:11 PM  3/11/2021, 1:28:07 PM   28m 56s TEST18@test.com Presenter 
Hugh, Grant V.  3/11/2021, 1:00:08 PM   3/11/2021, 1:28:13 PM   28m 5s  TEST5@test.com  Organizer 
Cole, Brad R.   3/11/2021, 1:27:03 PM 3/11/2021, 1:28:07 PM 1m 4s   TEST4@test.COM  Presenter";

            try
            {
                foreach (var rec in ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv)
                    .HeaderLineAt(7)
                    .WithDelimiter("\t")
                    .ConfigureHeader(h => h.HasHeaderRecord = true)
                    )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rec["Full Name"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(rec["Join Time"]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Good to know ;)

Comment: @cinchoo  For some reason I just get null after trying your solution.

Comment: post your sample raw CSV file.

Comment: Meeting Summary
Total Number of Participants 4
Meeting Title  Test
Meeting Start Time 3/11/2021, 12:57:48 PM
Meeting End Time 3/11/2021, 1:28:13 PM

Full Name Join Time Leave Time Duration Email Role
Smith, John. 3/11/2021, 12:57:48 PM 3/11/2021, 1:28:08 PM 30m 20s TEST39@test.com Presenter
Marshall, Micah D. 3/11/2021, 12:59:11 PM 3/11/2021, 1:28:07 PM 28m 56s TEST18@test.com Presenter
Hugh, Grant V. 3/11/2021, 1:00:08 PM 3/11/2021, 1:28:13 PM 28m 5s TEST5@test.com Organizer
Cole, Brad R. 3/11/2021, 1:27:03 PM 3/11/2021, 1:28:07 PM 1m 4s TEST4@test.COM Presenter

Comment: @Cinchoo you could use the above data

Comment: See updates above, working sample for your CSV file